# Why My Java Application can't see the *.jrxml?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

My project has the following architecture :
[image]

My template is "report1.jrxml", then when i excute this code :

```
  TableModel model = (TableModel) masterTable.getModel();    
  JRTableModelDataSource data = new JRTableModelDataSource(model);
  String reportSource ="report1.jrxml";
  try {
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,data);
      } catch (JRException ex) 
      {
            Logger.getLogger(master.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
```

I get this error(I'm sorry for the french language, but is quite understandable :p):

```
Grave: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jrxml (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:176)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:171)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:448)
    at testjasper.master.jButton1ActionPerformed(master.java:319)
    at testjasper.master.access$900(master.java:25)
    at testjasper.master$FormListener.actionPerformed(master.java:259)
```

Netbeans says that the file can't be found , but as you can see in the screenshot, its exists ?
How can I solve this "problem" ? 
rather, what's the problem ?
My regards. :p

Comment: Did you try adding the package directory to the path?  i.e. `testjasper/report1.jrxml'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper reports can't see it because the file is an embedded resource (it doesn't exist as a file, but a entry in the Jar file)

You need to get a reference to it by using `getClass().getResource("/testjasper/report1.jrxml")` which will return a `URL`.

From memory, you should be able to Jasper a `InputStream`, this can be achieved by using `URL#openConnection`

Comment: From our experience, it's normally easier (not to mention faster) to deliver precompiled reports instead of compiling it at runtime